# When clicked on an appended div, nothing happens even when using .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to re-create a color guess game where you click on divs that are random colors and you have to guess which one it asks for.  However, when I try to add difficulty by adding more divs using the .append function, the divs do not respond to clicks.  I have tried using .on("click", function(){}), and still not working.

```
$(function() {
  var initialTrys = 58;
  var difficulty = 9;
  //End of Game Settings
  var trys = initialTrys;
  $("#col").html(getRandomColor());
  $("#try").html(trys);
  run(difficulty);
  cor();
  $(".color").on("click", function() {
    var thisColor = $(this).css("backgroundColor");
    if (trys > 0) {
      trys--;
      $("#try").html(trys);
    } else if (trys === 0) {
      $("#alert").html("No More Tries").css("color", "red");
      // e.preventDefault();
      // return false;
    }
    console.log("clicked");
    if (thisColor == $("#col").html() && trys !== 0) {
      $("#alert").html("You Got It!").css("color", "green");
      $(this).siblings().addClass("clicked").css("backgroundColor", thisColor);
      console.log("correct");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }
  });

  $("#reset").on("click", function() {
    trys = initialTrys;
    $("#alert").html("");
    $("#try").html(trys);

    $(".color").each(function() {
      $(this)
        .addClass("color")
        .removeClass("clicked")
        .css("backgroundColor", getRandomColor());
    });
    $("#col").html(getRandomColor());
    cor();
  });
  function getRandomColor() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var color = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    return color;
  }
  function cor() {
    $(".color")
      .eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".color").length))
      .css("backgroundColor", $("#col").html());
  }
  $("#diffSlide").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      $("#diff").html("Easy").css("color", "green");
      $(".colorWrapper").children().remove();
      run(difficulty);
    } else if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $("#diff").html("Medium").css("color", "orange");
      $(".colorWrapper").children().remove();
      run(difficulty*2);
    } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
      $("#diff").html("Hard").css("color", "red");
      $(".colorWrapper").children().remove();
      run(difficulty * 3);
    }
  });
  function randColor() {
    $(".color").each(function() {
      $(this).css("backgroundColor", getRandomColor());
    });
  }
  function run(difficulty) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= difficulty; i++) {
      $(".colorWrapper").append("<div class='color'></div>");
      randColor();
      if (i % 3 === 0) {
        $(".colorWrapper").append("<br />");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Note: When the slider does not move, it works fine it is just when you try to change the difficulty.

Comment: Is it $(".color").on("click", function() that is not functioning?

Comment: It is the click function that doesn't work but only when I append a new div using the $("diffslide")

Comment: I take it my answer below did not help?

Comment: No, it didn't solve the problem that I was looking for, however, I probably should've been more specific when explaining my problem.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not attaching a click handler to the newly appended div when it is appended. Abstract your `$(".color").on("click", function() {...}` into something like:

```
function attachClickHandler(){
  $(".color").on("click", function() {...} //from ln 10 of your code
}
```

Then you can call `attachClickHandler()`on ln 10 as well as after the append in `run()`. This will attach the click handler both when the code initially runs as well as after the new div is appended.

Comment: I am not familiar with the attachClickHandler(){}.  How would I put it into my code, would I have to replace attachClickHandler() with $(".color").on("click", function() {...}?  I am still a beginner in javascript/jQuery so apologies for my nooby questions

Comment: Thanks so much, exactly what I needed!

Comment: @StuartFong Please mark the question as answered =)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you.

```
$(document).on("click", ".color", function(){

})
```